# Executing multiple tests with same value coming from Excelsheet. using @DataProvider

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a class where all the tests are written. I have 3 values in XL sheet where test1 and test2 should be executed with first value in Data sheet and then with 2nd value in Data sheet.

but now with the below code test1 is getting reexecuted with all the values in xl sheet and then test2 is getting executed.

```
public class Test() {

    @Test(dataProvider="DP1")
    public void test1() {
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods={"test1"})
    public void test2() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TestNg` dependency doesn't work this way.

In your case `test2` is dependent on `test1` and `test2` would only be executed after the execution of `test1` is finished, so here test1 is using `DataProvider` and it would be finished when it runs with all the data sets. Once the execution is done for `test1` then the control will go to `test2`.

So if you want to run 2 test cases with same dataset:

1. Don't make them dependent and run both of them with `@DataProvder`
2. Put the entire code in a single test case and then run (in case you don't want 2 test cases)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have implemented option:2. Included entire code in single @Test